# Are there any recent studies about tablet users behaviours and trends?

Tags: android, research, ipad, tablet

I am looking at studies about iPad and Android tablet behaviours and habits. Are there any difference between iPad and Android tablet users?

Comment: With regards to what? There're too many human bevaiours related to tablet use.

Comment: I am assuming @antonella just want's general data that helps understanding how tablets are being adopted and what the current trends are in behavior and use. Or is there a more specific question you could give us?

Comment: @JeroenEijkhof: In that case, it's a very broad request.

Comment: I agree that this is too broad to work with as is. There are lots of differences between Android and iOS users, but what specifically are you wondering? I've seen studies like Demographics, bandwidth usage ect.

Comment: @BenBrocka - Should he have to ask 4 questions? 
One for behaviors concerning iPad, one for trends concerning ipad, one for behaviors concerning android, one for trends concerning android. The question is big yes, but a great one for us to keep working on and updating as a community. Or at least help him narrow down the question. Maybe give an answer as to an overall framework that he can start his search from. Everyone starts out big like this when they don't really know much and then narrow down as more knowledge is acquired. This way he got almost nothing but critique for the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Jakob Nielsen**, the '[King of Usability](http://www.useit.com/jakob/)', [gave an interview](http://blog.utest.com/testing-the-limits-with-jakob-nielsen-part-i/2011/04/) in April 2011 where he outlined some general trends and user preferences for tablet usabilty.

He also did a multiyear iPad usability study. Part 1 is [here](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/ipad-1st-study.html) and Part 2 is [here](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/ipad.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is one article by LukeW on the use of tablets at Home VS Mobile use of tablets.
http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1518

The insight here is that we can see indicators showing tablets are used more at home or in places with Wi-Fi connections than actually using them on-the-go. For instance I know a lot of people report using smartphones in the bathroom, I image less people pick out an iPad in that situation :)

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any difference between iPad and Android tablet users?

As for why people buy Android tablets, reasons I've seen include:

- having a perception that Apple's "walled garden" is a bad thing
- money (iPads are generally more expensive than android options like the Kindle Fire)
- preference for open source solutions
- a desire/need for some connectivity or software not supported by the iPad (SD cards, Flash, etc.)